# Blazor WebAssembly "Virtualize" Table: How to scroll to an entry with a certain key into display? How to know, what is visible?

Tags: blazor-webassembly

like to use the Virtualize component in a client side Blazor app.
Is there a possibility to get control over what is visible?

How can I scroll an entry (eg by @key) into view?
How can I find out, which @keys are visible?

```
  <Virtualize Items="@forecasts">
    <tr @key="context.Index">
        <td>@context.Index</td>
        <td>@context.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
        <td>@context.TemperatureC</td>
        <td>@context.TemperatureF</td>
        <td>@context.Summary</td>
      </tr>
    </Virtualize>
```